# Bessel function difference

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, asymptotics, approximation, bessel-functions

Hello I'm looking for estimates for the difference

$I_{\nu+1}(x)-I_{\nu}(x)$

where $I_{\nu}$ is the modified Bessel functions of the first kind of order, $\nu\in \mathbb{N}$ is a positive integer and $x>0$ a positive real number.
Thank you very much!

Comment: This is a gentle reminder to accept an answer if your question has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Let $D_\nu(x):=I_{\nu+1}(x)-I_\nu(x)$

$\underline{\text{Positive }\nu}$

For small $x$ or large $\nu$ we have the [asymptotic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Asymptotic_forms)

$$
I_\nu(x)\sim\frac{1}{\Gamma(\nu+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^\nu \qquad ;\qquad x\ll\sqrt{\nu+1}
$$

Simplifying, we find

$$
D_\nu(x)\sim\frac{1}{\Gamma(\nu+2)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^\nu\left[\frac{x}{2}-(\nu+1) \right] \qquad ;\qquad x\ll\sqrt{\nu+1}
$$

For which the leading order is

$$
D_\nu(x)\sim-\frac{1}{\Gamma(\nu+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^\nu \qquad ;\qquad x\ll\sqrt{\nu+1} \tag{1}
$$

Which is also valid for negative *non-integer* $\nu$. The case $\nu=0$ requires a little care

$$
D_0(x) \sim \frac{x}{2}-1  \qquad ;\qquad x \to 0
$$

Here is a plot of the ratio exact/leading order for a few $\nu$ values:

[image]

For large $x$ and *fixed* $\nu$ we have the [asymptotic form](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.40)

$$
I_\nu(x)\sim\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{2\pi x}} \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{-1}{x}\right)^k a_k(\nu) \qquad ;\qquad x \to \infty 
$$

Where the coefficients $a_k(\nu)$ are defined [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.17#i). At leading order, we find

$$
D_\nu(x) \sim -\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{8\pi x^3}}(1+2\nu) \qquad ;\qquad x \to \infty \tag{2}
$$

Which is also valid for negative $\nu \neq -1/2$. Here is a plot of the ratio exact/leading order for a few $\nu$ values:

[image]

$\underline{\text{Exact result at }\nu=-1/2}$

Looking at the recurrence relations for the modified Bessel functions $K$, we find the exact result

$$
D_{-1/2}(x)=-\frac{2}{\pi}K_{1/2}(x) \tag{3}
$$

$\underline{\text{Negative }\nu}$

For $\nu<0$ we have [the connection formula](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.27)

$$
I_{-\nu}(x)=I_\nu(x)+\frac{2}{\pi} \sin(\nu \pi) K_\nu(x) \tag{4}
$$

From which we find the 'reflection formula' for any integer $\nu$

$$
D_{-\nu}(x)=-D_{\nu-1}(x) \tag{5}
$$

Eq (5) allows us to extend (1) to negative integers

$$
D_{-\nu}(x) \sim \frac{1}{\Gamma(\nu)}\left(\frac{x}{2} \right)^{\nu-1} \qquad ; \qquad x \to 0 \quad , \quad \nu =2,3,4 \dots\tag{6}
$$

As an aside, we could try to get the asymptotic behavior directly from the differential equation for $D_\nu$, with standard local analysis. From Bessel's equation for $I_\nu$ and $I_{\nu+1}$ we find the inhomogeneous equation

$$
x^2D_\nu''+xD_\nu'-(x^2+\nu^2)D_\nu=(2\nu+1)I_{\nu+1}
$$

Where $I_{\nu+1}$ is known. Not really necessary here as we already know the asymptotic forms of $D_\nu$.

Comment: I think it would be less confusing if you use $a_k(\nu)$ in place of $c_k(\nu)$ to be consistent with the linked DLMF page. They are the same thing. I corrected some typos for you as well.

Comment: @Gary Thank you. Good point about notation. I have expunged the $c_k$

Comment: Perhaps you can also address the issue of vanishing leading orders. For example what happens when $1/\Gamma(\nu+1)=0$ or $\nu=-\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @Gary Well spotted. I did notice these require special care. Since the question specified $\nu \in \mathbb{N}^+$ I didn't explore that further. Will think on it...